# Rewrite url by htaccess to display question mark

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a the following url:

```
Http://localhost/mydomain.com/?a=ax&b=bx&c=cx
```

I want the url like:

```
Http://localhost/mydomain.com/ax/bx/?c=cx
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried:
`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\?\([a-zA-Z0-9=]+)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2`

But, question mark '?' is not display :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /?a=$1&b=$2 [L,QSA]
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: You have to check your Apache's error.log for this as this code works pretty well for me.

Comment: I find a code the following:`RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/\+([a-z]+)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3`

Result: `localhost/mydomain.com/a/b/+c`

I want to change plus mark "+" to be "?=". But, when I change to question mark is not work. I want such as: `localhost/mydomain.com/a/b/?c=cx`

Comment: You must focus on the originally stated problem in your question. This rule is to support `http://localhost/mydomain.com/ax/bx/?c=cx` URL, I have tested it and it works well.

Comment: Didn't understand your question. What happens when you enter `http://localhost/mydomain.com/ax/bx/?c=cx` URL in browser?

Comment: Object not found!
Error 404

Why?

Comment: What is purpose of `/mydomain.com/` folder? Is this .htaccess located inside `/mydomain.com/`?